# when Im navigating a view the view is not display from the starting point but instead its displaying from the previous view leftover point

Tags: angular

I'm working on an angular project when I'm trying to navigate a view, the view is not loading from its starting point but instead, it's displaying from the previous view last visited point.
Please help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can not help if we have no code , please update your question and add code to it.